# cannot get span to go to new line

Tags: html, css

I cannot get my spans to go to new lines. they should sit next to the image

Here is my HTML:

```
<h2>Club Profile Card</h2>
<div class="clubprofilecard">   
    <h3><a href=""><img src=""/>Row 1
    <span>Row 2</span>
    <span>Row 3</span>
    <span>Row 4</span>
    </a></h3>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.clubprofilecard {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    /**border-bottom:1px solid #d0d0d0;*/
}
.clubprofilecard h3{
    position:relative;
    font:18px/24px DinWebCond,Sans-serif;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-left:90px;
    margin:0px 0px 15px 0px;
}
.clubprofilecard h3 a{
    color:#f06000;
    border:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.clubprofilecard img {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius:3px;
}
.clubprofilecard h3 a span
{
    white-space:nowrap;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;   
}

.clubprofilecard h2 {
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 font:22px/22px DinWebCond,Sans-serif;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
```

And here is the resulting output:

[image]

Not quite sure what to do here.

Comment: Why are you using spans instead of DIV, spans are inline where DIV is a block element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.clubprofilecard h3 a span
{
    white-space:nowrap;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;   
}
```

Try this:

```
.clubprofilecard h3 a span
{
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:block;   
}
```